# Role has encountered an error and has stopped

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am facing problem very similar to problem what we have in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490505/asp-net-mvc-5-2-2-on-azure) question.

We have a standard MVC5 application that we have deployed on Windows Azure using webrole.

After deploying I can see below error message on visual studio 'Microsoft Azure Activity Log' window

```
Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation.
```

I can see below error message on management console.

```
Restarting (Role has encountered an error and has stopped. Sites were deployed. [2014-10-22T04:46:57Z])
```

I found below error message in event viewer. ( inside VM )

```
 The description for Event ID 1007 from source Windows Azure Runtime 2.4.0.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

    2232
    WaIISHost
    Role entrypoint could not be created: System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
    -- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    File name: 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

    WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
    To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
    Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
    To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

     ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
       at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)

    the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

I don't know why its referring to version 4.0.0.0
My  section of web.config file looks like this.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem.  I found location of WaIISHost.exe and modify existing **WaIISHost.exe.config** file by adding binding redirect statements to it.

You can find this file under **'E:\base\x64'**

Answer (score 2):

Your web.config controls w3wp.exe, but your callstack indicates that you are crashing in WaIISHost.exe.  You have a couple options:

1. Why are you referencing System.Web.Mvc in your role entry point DLL (typically WebRole.cs)?  If you can refactor this part of your code then you don't have to worry about loading this DLL and all of it's dependencies in your WaIISHost process.
2. Create an app.config with the same binding redirect you have in your web.config.

Comment: I will try to check first point. I am not quite sure about.  For a quick fix I was trying for 2nd option.  I created file App.conifg ONLY one section under <configuration> i.e. <runtime> containing all binding redirect.  I placed this file under 'E:\sitesroot\0' where my site is deployed and also placed it under 'E:\approot' But still I am getting same error.  I also tried renaming file to'WallSHost.exe.config'  but in vain.  Any other input from your side?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with version 5.1 and I had to set the MVC dll copytolocal=true. I believe it is related to the previous MVC security update. This is Microsoft's brute force away of insisting you update MVC.